# Нажание на Row в TableView

Tags: java, javafx, события, клавиатура

По умолчанию в `TableView` нажатие на строки происходит с помощью 2-х клавиш мыши - левой и правой. Как можно реализовать нажатие на строку исключительно левой кнопкой мыши?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример отключения для правой кнопки мыши:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn();
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()));

        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);

        tableView.getItems().addAll("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");

        tableView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) event.consume();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.